Identify this set: mostly red & white bricks
I'm looking for instructions for a incomplete kit I got.  Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.  Nephew loves to put them together with instructions.  Packaging shows 7, 8, 9 with the number 146R7 and a smaller number 135149.

Based on the technic 90-degree connectors and looking at what sets have it in yellow, plus the sheer amount of white & red window frames and parts, that's part of 60110 "Fire Station" from 2016.


Once you know the set number (60110), it's trivial to find instructions in the customer service section of the lego website.
